# prevent .click to run when page reloads

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i created a notification on my page and it post the data if the status is equal to 0 then update it to 1 after display.

so what happens on the notif badge it shows how many data that is being post.

and the numbers will be removed on the badge if i clicked the notif icon..

but the problem i encounter is that the numbers disappears when i reload/refresh the page..

here is my code..

```
setInterval(function () {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:'functions/get_newtest.php',
            dataType:'JSON',
            success: function (data) {

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                $('#dropdown_notif').append('<li><a href="#">'+data[i].userfullname+' '+data[i].message+' '+'from'+' '+data[i].page_from+'</a></li>');
                $('#nt_count').html(($('#nt_count').html()) ? parseInt($('#nt_count').html()) + 1 : 1);
                console.log($('#nt_count'));
            }   

            if(data.length){

                $.ajax({
                    url:'functions/update_test.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    dataType:'JSON',
                    data:{id:data[0].id},
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            }

            },
            error: function (status) {
                console.log(status.responseText);
            }
          });
        },10000);
```

and here is the button function i use to remove the numbers when clicked.

```
$('li.dropdown a:has("#nt_count")').click(function () {

             $(this).find('span.notification').html(null);

          });
```

is there a way to not disappear the numbers on the badge when the page reloads?.cause what i wanted to do is the numbers will only be removed if clicked..

Comment: Just a note, $("#nt_count") is unique so is enough as selector, dont need li.dropdown etc...

Comment: Maybe you can make a php query to count data you need directly on document.